# Firestore set function not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to move my all posts to firestore using cloud functions

```
exports.copyPosts = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    var i = 0;
    var username;
    db.ref("feeds").child("all").limitToLast(2000).once("value", function (postSnap) {
            console.log(postSnap.numChildren());

        postSnap.forEach(function(topic){
                i = i + 1;


                    firestore.collection("topics").doc(i+"").set({
                        caption: topic.child("caption").val(),
                        time: topic.child("time").val(),
                        username: topic.child("username").val(),
                        category: topic.child("category").val(),
                        pic: topic.child("pic").val()

                    })

                if(postSnap.numChildren()==i){
                    res.contentType('application/json');
                    res.status(200).send("Success");
                }
            });
        });

});
```

It returns success. And before that I used this loop to copy posts to another real time database location and it worked.

But for firestore no datas are added and no errors in log is showing..

Comment: Have you tried logging something inside the forEach do see what it's doing?  Have you considered paying attention to the promises that are being generated from the writes, and only allowing the function to terminate when they're all resolved?

Comment: I agree with @DougStevenson, some of value of object may undefined into `set ({...})` . Also need to enclose double quotes of caption, time, username, category and pic if they are not a variable.

Answer (score 2):

I can insert data to firestore with cloud function.
You may first pass the data to the variable then put the variable in the set() operation. Hope this can help you

```
exports.insertDB = functions.https.onRequest((request,response) =>
{
  var firstname_input = request.query.name;
  db.collection("user").doc(firstname_input).set({
          first_name : firstname_input,
          last_name : "Chow",
          hobby : "Swimming"
        })
  response.send("Inserted a new user, name: " + firstname_input);
});
```